# how to Print Exception in txt file in java

Tags: java

```
public class myclass
{
    // Main method
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        // Stream to write file
 try {
    int a=100;
     int b=a/0;
    System.out.println(b);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}       


    }   
}
```

This my code i want to Print what Evre Exception is coming in E:\logfile.txt. please help me i am Unable to do this .

Comment: You need to replace `e.printStackTrace`...

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use some logging framework, e.g. Log4j?

Comment: how i will replacee. printStackTrace please hlep

Comment: actully i have to Upload on server and what Ever Exception will come need to collect in .txt file in E:\\log.txt

Comment: @AnilKumar That is what a logging library does and rewriting one is probably going to be a waste of time.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `printStackTrace()` overload which takes a [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) parameter:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace(java.io.PrintStream)

Alternatively, use a logging framework, such as [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a static method of a class for this.

```
public class Logbook {

    // path to logbook
    private String path = "E:\logfile.txt";

    // static method
    public static boolean Log(String message) {
        try {
            File f = new File(path);
            // append the text file
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file,true);

            // append text to file by using a buffer
            BufferedWriter bw  = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
            fileWriter.append(message);

            // close buffer
            bufferFileWriter.close();

            // tell that it has succeed
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and to log the message,

```
catch (Exception e) {
    // log file
    if (Logbook.Log(e.getMessage())) System.out.println("Error caught and got logged");
    else System.out.println("Error caught but logging has failed");
}
```